# UI Bootstrap dropdown-append-to="appendToEl"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with UI Bootstrap Dropdown. I want to append the Dropdown to a specific element.

I modified their Plunker Example to show my [Problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/kaA5Vsx690ci2qVCUPlC?p=preview)

So I want to append the Dropdown to the bottom of the Listelement to look like this

[image: look like this].

The problem with the Inline Dropdown is that the Listelement is `overflow:hidden` .

I tried using `dropdown-append-to-body` but as you can see in the example it doesn't scroll with the the element.

Also it would be great if the Dropdown would append to the box in witch its button is placed.

I think I need to modify the `$scope.appendToEl` but I can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Were you able to get an answer to this?